# Get rid of unwanted / in address bar using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When a user enters http://example.com/thequery/, that is what they see in the address bar and PHP gets "/thequery/" as the query string which is the wanted behavior. However if the user enters example.com?thequery in the address bar as soon as the server responds they see example.com/?thequery and PHP gets "thequery" as query string, that part (the query) is OK however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove or prevent the "/" from the url in the address bar of second example, while retaining the correct behaviour of the first example so the user sees only example.com?thequery at all times for the second example.  Can someone please help.

Comment: The slash you're talking about is always required after the domain. If you request domain.tld?something, it will always be redirected to domain.tld/?something, without fail. There is nothing you can do to change that behaviour - this is by intention.

Comment: Thankyou, that does appears to be the case.  I wonder therefore as in the case of the site in question, the query in the "GET" format is merely ignored by the server, is it then possible to remove the query part and just return the base URL ie example.tld to the browser, just as if the ignored "?something" was not even entered at all? using htaccess that is, but leave example.tld/something in tact.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm afraid. Are you trying to prevent users from using the query string variants? Example: redirect `example.tld/?something` --> `example.com/something`

Comment: @Mike, sorry I should have made that clearer.  By intent users can load a dynamic page using example.tld/virtual-folder/, which as U can see from the above htaccess loads example.tld/index.php with the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] var being /virtual-folder/ ... all good!

Comment: @Mike. php processes and loads appropriate html to browser!   However if a user enters into browser example.tld?whatever that also gets passed to php as query but  is ignored by php code ... that behaviour is also intended and OK. I could do a php header redirect to plain url which would achieve the desired result (no query string shown) but that is messy, I would like htaccess to remove the query string when and only when the user enters example.tld?whatever but not when user enters example.tld/virtual-folder/. Is that do-able? Thanks

Comment: That should be ... "serves" appropriate html to browser

Comment: Posting this as a comment as it is not an answer to the original question: http://hastebin.com/agohigajog.apache

Comment: Also adding my first comment as the answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @Mike, Thankyou for the answer I have up-voted it but my reputation does not show it publicly and for the script on hastebin, it was what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash you're talking about is always required after the domain. If you request `domain.tld?something`, it will *always* be redirected to `domain.tld/?something`, without fail.

There is nothing you can do to change that behaviour - this is by intention.

> If
>      the abs_path is not present in the URL, it MUST be given as "/" when
>      used as a Request-URI for a resource (section 5.1.2).

Source: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html#ixzz0kGbpjYWa